# YouTube XML Feed Error

Tags: php, xml, api, rss, youtube

I've got a page on a website that's pulling my favorites feed from YouTube and embedding them into site.

The problem is it's working 80% of the time, but the other 20% of the time i'm getting errors on the page - nothing in the code is changing to cause this, so i'm wondering what might be causing this, or if there's a better way to do what i'm doing...

**The Error I'm gettings is a 403 Forbidden** when retrieving the XML feed... here's what it looks like (note: the line numbers won't match exactly, because i've simplified the code sample below.

The XML feed in question is here: 
`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/umarchives/favorites`

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/umarchives/favorites) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /mnt/stor3-wc2-dfw1/web/content/videos.php on line 42

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/umarchives/favorites" in /mnt/stor3-wc2-dfw1/web/content/videos.php on line 42

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /mnt/stor3-wc2-dfw1/web/content/videos.php on line 47
```

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<?php
    // set feed URL
    $YouTubeUsername = "umarchives";

    $feedURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$YouTubeUsername."/favorites";

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

    // iterate over entries in feed
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {  

    // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
    $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    $attrs = $media->group->content->attributes();

    $videoURL = $attrs['url'];
    $videoURL = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $videoURL);
    $videoURL = str_replace("/v/","/embed/",$videoURL);

    $videoTitle = $media->group->title;

    echo "<iframe class='youtube-player' width='300' height='225' src='$videoURL'></iframe>\n";
    echo "<br>\n";

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, i've added it to the question, it's a 403 Forbidden error when retrieving the XML feed...

Comment: What does the error looks like exactly?

Comment: ok, i've added the exact text of the error above, sorry for the lack of detail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be validating the result of `$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);` [per the Google error validation docs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses.html). Then you can print out the actual message that comes along with the 403 code, or possibly decide to retry the request.  If it's a random occurrence my guess is a quota limit issue, but the actual error information will likely tell you exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

`MYUSERNAME` is not a valid username. Add your own youtube username!

Comment: thanks, but i just replaced it for sake of this example. it does have the correct username in place, and again, it does work 80% of the time...

Comment: Hey Dan, your error shows that you are using MYUSERNAME. Please update your error!

Comment: The error message is updated with the propery username now. You can substitute it with any YouTube username, as long as the favorites feed is publicly viewable.  You can also directly view the XML feed here: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/umarchives/favorites`

Answer (score 0):

When I call your feed URL in browser (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/wfptv/favorites) I receive this error:

```
 Favorites of requested user are not public.
```

Make your feed public, and the failure should be gone.